# HttpMethodBase vs HttpRequestBase

Tags: java, apache, http, request, httprequest

What is the difference in usage of 
    *org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodBase*
and
    *org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpRequestBase* to execute a Http request?

So for example to execute a GET request I can do

```
clientX.executeMethod(new GetMethod(uri));
```

or

```
clientY.execute(new HttpGet(uri));
```

So why both is provided by apache? Respectively when I should use which one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically since apache evolves its APIs also evolve. The HttpRequestBase is part of the new HttpClient implementation after version 4.0. So it is encouraged to use the newer implementation.

HttpGet is the newer version of GetMethod. Here is the statement from apache:

> HttpClient is a HTTP/1.1 compliant HTTP agent implementation based on
>   HttpCore. It also provides reusable components for client-side
>   authentication, HTTP state management, and HTTP connection management.
>   HttpComponents Client is a successor of and replacement for Commons
>   HttpClient 3.x. Users of Commons HttpClient are strongly encouraged to
>   upgrade.